# try except AttributeError bugs

Tags: python, except

I'm trying to add `try` and `except` to my code but it does not work.

```py
def _get_table_df(self, table):
        
    l = module.send_command(name='Read', attributes={'type': table, 'method':'all', 'limit':'1', 'enable_custom':1})
    so = BeautifulSoup(l.text,'xml')
    columns = []
    try:
        for x in list(so.find(table).children):
            columns.append(x.name)
         df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    except AttributeError:
        return "no data"
        
    return df
```

The error pointing to `try` line says

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'

Comment: Is everything correct with the indent in your code?

Comment: And could you add a full traceback?

Comment: I believe you have added a extra space somewhere which is causing the issue. You can try adding the `except:` block generalized and then see

Comment: I think your xml file is not suit for your code.

Comment: @FerhatMousavi what does it mean?

Comment: exception said that your children variable is None. It means BeautifulSoup cant parse your xml file properly.

Comment: @FerhatMousavi yes you are right, I got this part too. Thats why I tried to do try except as this code is part of for loop so other objects are working fine.